# How to increase the maximum number of participants in Office Communicator conference

Tags: lync, ms-office-communicator

We often want to make quick announcements to our group of 20 people using Office Communicator, so we highlight a group of contacts and start a new IM session. However, only a maximum of 10 people are able to join the conversation; after the maximum number of people join, all other invitees get the message:

> Cannot connect to the conference because it is full. Contact the conference leader for more information.

Is there a way to increase the maximum number of participants?

Comment: What version of Office Communicator are you using?

Comment: Office Communicator 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into your forest, properties, global properties, meetings tab, go into one of the profiles.  The maximum meeting size directly ties into the max people who can be in a multiparty IM at the same time as well.  It's tied into the initiator of the session as well...so whoever started the IM (whatever his/her policy is set to) defines how many people can enter the multiparty IM.

I had the problem because I initially set it to 10 because I thought this setting was related to Live Meeting only.  Live Meeting uses more bandwidth and we don't have a ton so I restricted it.  People where then having problems sending IM's to distribution lists.  After testing and once I figured this out I had to bump the number up.

This number also only comes into play when users are connected......so if I restict to 15 and I have 20 people in my DL, but 7 are offline, I'm really only going to connect with 13....which is under the 15 maximum meeting size.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'll award the bounty when I'm allowed to.